# solaris- find files only current directory

Tags: solaris

I'm asking what looks to be a tired old question :)
I just want to find files in the current directory... suppose they're .mp3 files
and I don't want it to branch out further.

I'm hitting too many dead ends here but stubbornly want this to work in Solaris :p

This almost looked promising: find . -xdev -name "*.mp3"
as did find . -name '*.[Mm][Pp][3]' -prune

Mostly the reason I'm doing find is because I had enough trouble trying to search for files made in the last few minutes, so am stretching out something like  find . -name "*.[Mm][Pp][3]" -prune -newer /tmp/emptyfile |wc -l
Where I'm constantly creating a new file to compare new files against.

And that took enough stress to do so I'd like to keep that if possible.

Manual on find says depth is always true but it doesn't apply to files.

Overall what I did do looks good enough but that's a bit of distress.

Answer (score 3):

Ah alright, this seems to finally work out for Solaris =)

find .  ! -name . -prune  -type f -name "*.[Mm][Pp]3"

Adapted from a post .
http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/180505-some-advice-please-non-recursive-find.html

Comment: thank you for this! and based on other answers on SO, you can pass the full path plus a period into find to avoid making it the current dir as such (adds a unix comment at the end, cannot format in SOcomment):
find YourPath/. ! -name . -prune -type f -name "*.[Mm][Pp]3 #
"! -name . -prune" is the part that prunes away sub directories, then you can add other conditions as needed